# What does select "system.collection.Arraylist"?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm studying the ArrayList, and the guide that I have, the example code is this:

```
var sample= new ArrayList();
```

I was reporting the error, and click with the right button, then going to "resolve" and "system.ArrayList Collection", the problem rightly has disappeared.

I knew I had to do so because I found a guide but I do not understand the reason.

What exactly is the "system.collection.arrayList", because without it, Visual Studio reporting error?

What is it and what does it mean?

Thank you

Comment: _"I'm studying the ArrayList"_ waste of time, use the strongly typed `List<T>` in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

It means `ArrayList` class is defined under `System.Collections` namespace. And you need either use it by typing it's fully qualified name which is `System.Collections.ArrayList`, or include the namespace with a using directive (`using System.Collections;`) and use it without namespace.

For more information have a look at [using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The use of ArrayList is not enabled by default with C#.

In order to use ArrayList you must call "System.Collections.ArrayList", so at compile time the server will know to include the ArrayList functionality.